# Stacking lists of lists into a matrix in R

Tags: r, list, concatenation

I'm trying to get some data from a large Baseball database in a nice format. It's a MySQL database so I use RMySQL to access it.

Problem is, the easiest way to retrieve the data I need is using sapply, as I need to vary an index:

```
myf <- function(ab){
search <- paste('select pitch_type, des from pitches where ab_id=', ab)
query <- dbSendQuery(con2,search)
return(fetch(query,n=-1))
}

pitches <- sapply(players$ab_id,myf,simplify="array")
```

But it is very hard to access this data, as it returns a list of lists:

```
> mode(pitches[,1])
>[1] "list"
```

Since I have two columns of different length in each list, is there an easy way to just stack all of these into a matrix/data frame? I have tried many things to no success.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to join your data in a single data.frame? (Presumably with 3 columns: ab_id, pitch_type, des). Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: I know there is a `rbind.fill` in the `plyr` pacakge which `‘rbind’s a list of data frames filling missing columns with NA.`

Comment: Theo, yes that's what I'm trying to do (though in the example above I'm not retrieving ab_id). I'll check out plyr, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do this in one query using an `IN` clause?

Comment: Can you figure out a way to pass it a 2051 vector for the IN clause? paste just makes every entry in the vector a string.

Comment: I do it all the time, every day, as part of my job. But how you do it will depend on some particulars. Is the db expecting ab_id to be a number or a string? What's the max number of values that RMySQL will handle in an IN clause? (For ODBC connections I believe it can be as low as 999, which sometimes forces me to write code that does the query in 2-3 pieces.)

Comment: To get you started, in the case of strings: `paste0("('", paste(vec, collapse = "','"), "')")`.